# What is the maximum concentration of HNO3 (nitric acid) which may be handled outside of a hood?

Tags: acid-base, concentration, safety

Commercial stock solutions of HNO3 (nitric acid) are usually 70% w/w, and according to several MSDSs (e.g. [here](http://www.labchem.com/tools/msds/msds/LC17700.pdf)), it is dangerous to inhale it:

> > Symptoms/effects after inhalation : Irritation of the respiratory tract. Dry/sore throat. Corrosion of the upper respiratory tract.
> >     Coughing. 
> > FOLLOWING SYMPTOMS MAY APPEAR LATER: Respiratory difficulties. Possible
> >     inflammation of the respiratory tract. Risk of lung edema. Blue/grey discolouration of the skin

What I want to know is what is the maximum concentration that 70% HNO3 can be diluted to, which may be safe to work outside of a hood? Are there guidelines/credible sources for such information?

Please note, this is **not** a medical question, it is a question of safety practice in a chemistry lab.

Comment: Why would you need to work outside the hood?  If you can, work with chemicals in the hood.

Comment: What he said! If possible keep it in a hood at all times.

Comment: And if it isn't possible to keep it in a hood you almost certainly need to rethink what you are trying to do. (Yes, my lab regularly uses small amounts of IPA outside of a hood to clean optics and vacuum equipment, but we sure would not use similarly small quantities of nitric acid.)

Comment: I can see why it may be _really_ dangerous for your throat to use _fuming_ HNO3, but normal conc. nitric acid shouldn't be, unless you sniff it on purpose.

Comment: This is a good question!  Probably everyone agrees that 0.0000001 mol / L of nitric acid in water is not particularly hazardous to handle outside the fume hood, and that concentrated nitric acid is very dangerous and must be handled in a fume hood.  Where is the in-between point?

Comment: I feel like the commenters are missing that the OP is not asking about the the *amount* of *concentrated* acid that can be handled outside the hood, he is asking about the _concentration_ of acid that can be handled outside the hood.

Comment: That's right, @Curt F., and I'll try to elaborate: my work is usually with low concentrations of 1% nitric acid, and the experienced students say it's not a problem to work with it outside of the hood. We prepare the 1% from 70% and this IS done in the hood, always. This is the background, and as Curt F. Put it nicely: what would be the cut-off point within this range?

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to inhalation risk and damage. Safety may depend on ventilation in the room, how close you approach the solution, and both the volume (or surface area), temperature and concentration, how you handle the solution, to what purpose it is put. If you are working in a lab ask someone associated with the lab in charge of safety.

Comment: I want to guess that this is mainly determined by the relevant legislation of whichever country you’re in, particularly your country’s equivalent of Germany’s MAK (maximal working-space concentration). Because these are set to be well below any truly hazardous limit.